# Python Pylons/Pyramid Cookies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, pylons

What is the best way to set and get cookies in pylons/pyramid?

```
Response.set_cookie('example_cookie_name', 'example', max_age=180*24*3600)
```

returns the error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/webob/response.py", line 1071, in set_cookie
    self.headerlist.append(('Set-Cookie', cookie)) 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'headerlist'
```

Comment: That should work, according to the docs for [`Response.set_cookie`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response.set_cookie). What's the full stacktrace? Alternatively use a session factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing something like this:

```
from pyramid.response import Response
Response.set_cookie('example_cookie_name', 'example', max_age=180*24*3600)
```

The problem is that `Response` is a class and you're calling its unbound method `set_cookie` passing a string in place of the `self` argument.

(Fun fact - in Python 2 the error is [much clearer](https://github.com/universe-proton/universe-topology/issues/3))

You need to either instantiate a new response object or simply use the `request.response` attribute.

Comment: How would I get the cookie? Thanks.

Comment: @TheAnonymous: that would be `request.cookies`, which is a dict-like object, so `request.cookies.get('example_cookie_name')` should do the trick